# What does it mean when みたいな is at the end of a sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, slang

「彼ももうちょっとがんばればよかったのに..、みたいな…。」

or

「なんか、お腹減った、みたいな…」

Just for some examples. Is it some sort of filler? I understand normal uses of みたい but I don’t understand what it means at the end of a sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you've heard expressions like みたいな気がする and みたいな感じがする.

みたいな is just a shorter form of that. They all mean something along the lines of

- I feel like
- I kinda think

Japanese use this expression to make the sentence softer/more careful/less sure, as to not present it as a fact, but just your humble opinion/feelings.